# JAX-RS POST file input stream is empty

Tags: java, file, post, jax-rs

I am trying to create a POST call that uploads file, here is my code:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadfile") 
@Produces({"application/json","application/xml"}) //the default result is json
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Authenticated
public Response saveFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                              @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition cdh) throws CompanyNotFoundException, UserUnauthorizedException, IllegalAccessException, WasteInvalidException, ItemNotFoundException, IOException{
    System.out.println(inputStream.available());

    return Response.ok("success").build();
}
```

but for some reason the received inputStream has 0 bytes always (use `inputStream.available() check`).
 I did the testing using Postman. [image]

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all looks right. Are you sure your assumption is correct about the stream being empty? Looking at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29):

> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

You might try reading from it and seeing if there's data present.

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't know that the available method for InputStream always return 0